# Migrating commit history from Gerrit to GitHub

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I have an existing repository on Gerrit(On premise) which has `master` branch as primary branch and want to migrate this repository to GitHub(Cloud) with `main` as the primary branch having commit history exactly like I have on `master` branch in Gerrit.
To accomplish this I have carried out the following steps:-

1. Created a clone of Gerrit repository on my local machine
2. Created an empty repository in GitHub having primary branch `main`
3. Changed the remote URL of repository on local machine which was pointing to Gerrit and made it point to the repository on GitHub
4. Created a replica of `master` branch and named it `MainReplica` by using `git checkout -b MainReplica`
5. Pushed this branch to remote by `git push -u origin MainReplica` which created a new branch `MainReplica` on GitHub with the required commit history

Now I want to create a pull request on `MainReplica` to be merged into `main` because I cannot directly commit to `main` branch since it is protected. However, I am unable to see any option to created a pull request as it shows me a message `There isn’t anything to compare. main and MainReplica are entirely different commit histories.` Now I don't know how I can go about this, any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an "exact replica" of the history, then you are busted if you are not allowed to push (force push, in this case) into `main`. If you do not mind having a *slightly different* history, then merge the new repo's branch into your MainReplica *locally*:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout MainReplica
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories -m "merging branches from 2 repos" origin/main
git push origin @
```

Now you will be able to create the PR because origin/main is part of the history of `MainReplica`.

Comment: Yes, it does create an extra merge commit but that's totally fine for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a git branch via

```
git branch -m master main
```

and then you will have the very same commit history.

Comment: I can have a `main` branch locally with the required commit history but I can't push local `main` to remote `main` as it is a protected branch, hence I have created a `master` replica called `MainReplica`  to be merged into the remote `main` branch via pull request, but it doesn't allow me to create the PR due to an error `There isn’t anything to compare. main and MainReplica are entirely different commit histories.`

Comment: @ParagKadam have you tried `git rebase --onto` or `git cherry-pick` ?